# How to get the true wifi scan results updated with the time

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager, indoor-positioning-system

I am developing wifi indoor positioning app for my research study. I get the attached wifi scan service and the broadcast receiver  from https://github.com/Talentica/WifiIndoorPositioning 
to get the wifi scan result and use it to get indoor location. 
My problem is the wifi scan results do not udate with moving from place to other with time, it seems give the privous scan result not new list. 
how can I edit it to get actual updated scan results with time

```
public class WifiService extends Service {

    private final String TAG = "WifiService";
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

    private WifiManager mWifiManager;
    private ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleReaderHandle;
    private ScheduledExecutorService mScheduler;
    private WifiData mWifiData;

    private long initialDelay = 0;
    private long periodReader = AppContants.FETCH_INTERVAL;
    List<ScanResult> mResults;

    /**
     * It creates a new Thread that it is executed periodically reading the last
     * scanning of WiFi networks (if WiFi is available).
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "WifiService onCreate");
        mWifiData = new WifiData();
        mWifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        scheduleReaderHandle = mScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleReader(), initialDelay, periodReader,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
          mResults = new ArrayList<ScanResult>() {};


    }


    /**
     * Kills the periodical Thread before destroying the service
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // stop read thread
        scheduleReaderHandle.cancel(true);
        mScheduler.shutdown();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Performs a periodical read of the WiFi scan result, then it creates a new
     * {@link WifiData ()} object containing the list of networks and finally it
     * sends it to the main activity for being displayed.
     */
    class ScheduleReader implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (mWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {

                mResults = mWifiManager.getScanResults();


                Log.d(TAG, "New scan result: (" + mResults.size() + ") networks found");
                // store networks
                mWifiData.addNetworks(mResults);
                // send data to UI
                Intent intent = new Intent(AppContants.INTENT_FILTER);
                intent.putExtra(AppContants.WIFI_DATA, mWifiData);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(WifiService.this).sendBroadcast(intent);
                mResults.clear();

            }
        }
    }
}
  public class MainActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000");
            mWifiData = (WifiData) intent.getParcelableExtra(AppContants.WIFI_DATA);

            if (mWifiData.getNetworks().size() != 0) {


               List<WifiDataNetwork> latestScanList = mWifiData.getNetworks();
                LocationWithNearbyPlaces loc = AlgorithmTxtDb.processingAlgorithms(fingerprintRefPointsList, routersList, latestScanList, 2);
}
} 

public class MainActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000");
            mWifiData = (WifiData) intent.getParcelableExtra(AppContants.WIFI_DATA);

            if (mWifiData.getNetworks().size() != 0) {



                List<WifiDataNetwork> latestScanList = mWifiData.getNetworks();
                LocationWithNearbyPlaces loc = AlgorithmTxtDb.processingAlgorithms(fingerprintRefPointsList, routersList, latestScanList, 2);

                }
            }

        }

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWifiData = null;
        // set receiver
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(AppContants.INTENT_FILTER));
        // launch WiFi service
        wifiServiceIntent = new Intent(this, WifiService.class);
        startService(wifiServiceIntent);
        // recover retained object
        mWifiData = (WifiData) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from android 9.0 
The latest version of android (android 9 (Pie)) had a new restrictions and limitations for WIFI scanning, as it is documented by android. They add throttling for the scan intervals for both of foreground and background scenarios to save the power consumption. 
 Android 9 and later: Each foreground app can scan four times in a 2-minute period. This allows for a burst of scans in a short time. All background apps combined can scan one time in a 30-minute period.
[android wifi scan](http://%20https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan#wifi-scan-throttling)
The following links represent the response of this throttling:
[links represent the response of this throttling](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-pie-throttling-wi-fi-scans-crippling-apps/), [link 2](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112688545), [link 3](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79906367#comment20), [link 4](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74882205)

Answer (score 1):

Add below dependency in your app.

```
implementation 'com.easyconnectlibrary.library:easyconnectlibrary:1.0.5'
```

Use below code to get wifi scan result every 10 second. However you can change 10 second to 5 second based on your requirement.

```
private WifiConnection mWifiConnection;
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWifiConnection = WifiConnection.getInstance(this);
    mWifiConnection.registerWifiScanListener(new WifiScanListener() {
        @Override
        public void onWifiScanList(List<ScanResult> scanResultList) {
            int i = 1;
            if (scanResultList.size() == 0) {
                Log.i("MainActivity Result " + i, "No Wifi available");
            } else {
                for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResultList) {
                    Log.i("MainActivity Result " + i, scanResult.SSID);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationServiceOff() {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Location service should be turned on");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(WIFI_SCAN_ERROR wifi_scan_error) {
            Log.i("MainActivity", wifi_scan_error + " Error");
        }
    });
    mHandler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Handler Started");
            mWifiConnection.getWifiScanList();

        }
    };
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                mHandler.post(runnable);
                try {
                     //sleep for 10 second before making another scan request
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

Comment: I need to get scan results for small intervals such as one second. your code and my code when decrease the thread sleep interval it give the previous  scan results (not new scan request with updated data) that because the sleep interval is less than the  limit scanResult requests per time (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan)

Answer (score 0):

An app requesting too many scans in a certain period of time. This may lead to additional
scan request rejections via "scan throttling" for both foreground and background apps.
Note: Apps holding android.Manifest.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS permission are exempted
from scan throttling.

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.NETWORK_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```